# Files created on external storage do not show up when device is mounted on Windows/Mac

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have a simple application that attempts to save some data to external storage on Android device (Nexus 4) to be later retrieved on PC (Windows or Mac).

The writing succeeds but when i try to retrieve the file using Android File Transfer on Mac or by Explorer on Windows the MyApp directory just isn't there.

If i use 'Root Explorer' app on the device itself i can see the directory and the file and all permissions look ok.

The application code is along the following lines:

```
        File extStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File path = new File(extStorageDir, "MyApp");
        File file = new File(path, "TestFile.txt");

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // ... write something

        os.close();
```

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: see [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888451/android-write-on-external-storage-using-getexternalstoragepublicdirectorystrin

Comment: see [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888451/android-write-on-external-storage-using-getexternalstoragepublicdirectorystrin

Answer (score 1):

see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57913/how-do-i-refresh-rescan-the-sd-memory-in-android-4-4-kitkat)

Use the app [sd scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.jerickson314.sdscanner), it seems to work on my Nexus 7 with android kitkat

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem with Android 4 and Mac os. I guess that you might be in the same situation. The solution was to rescan the sd storage using SDrescan.

This is described here: [Nexus 4 not showing files via MTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737261/nexus-4-not-showing-files-via-mtp)

Comment: Thanks! this code:       
`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));` 
resolved the problem

Comment: Thanks!ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));  worked for me (I'm testing my app with Android 4.4 and Mac)